# Utilising multiple columns to be the x-axis in ggplot2 for R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Desired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx8s7.png)

I wanted to obtain the above graph, and I tried using ggplot for it.

```
blue = c(83, 81, 80, 71, 69, 63, 63, 62, 54)
red = c(112, 96, 111, 141, 125, 89, 178, 107, 130)
loc = c("YISHUN", "WOODLANDS", "HOUGANG", "ANG MO KIO"  "TAMPINES", "SENGKANG", "GEYLANG", "BEDOK", "JURONG WEST")
tib = mutate(blue, red, loc)
ggplot(lst_compare, aes(x=c(wet, dry) ,y=loc)) +
  geom_point() + geom_segment(y=loc, x= wet, xend= dry, yend= loc)
```

I tried the above method, however, it seems I can't simply include multiple columns as the x value. Does anyone know how to include multiple columns as part of x-axis?

Comment: Unfortunately your example code is not reproducible. But you could add your points via two geom_points instead of trying to map two cols on one x, i.e. `geom_point(aes(wet, loc), color = ) + geom_point(aes(dry, loc), color = ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the mistakes in your reprex. I think it's best to pivot the data before plotting.

```r
library(tidyverse)
blue = c(83, 81, 80, 71, 69, 63, 63, 62, 54)
red = c(112, 96, 111, 141, 125, 89, 178, 107, 130)
loc = c("YISHUN", "WOODLANDS", "HOUGANG", "ANG MO KIO",  "TAMPINES", "SENGKANG", "GEYLANG", "BEDOK", "JURONG WEST")
tib = data.frame(blue, red, loc)

tib %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("blue", "red")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = value, y = loc, color = name), size = 2) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  geom_line(aes(x = value, y = loc)) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>